# Get combination of CD and description for PXSelector

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use a Selector to lookup up customers, and I want it to show the CD along with the description in the field.  I've seen this many times in Acumatica - and I thought I knew how to do it, but it's not working.  Here is my code:

```
     #region CustomerLookup
     public abstract class customerLookup : PX.Data.IBqlField
     {
     }
     protected string _CustomerLookup;
     [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
     [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Lookup")]
     [PXSelector(typeof(Customer.acctCD)
                ,typeof(Customer.acctCD)
                ,typeof(Customer.acctName)
                ,DescriptionField=typeof(Customer.acctName))]
     public virtual string CustomerLookup
     {
         get
         {
             return this._CustomerLookup;
         }
         set
         {
             this._CustomerLookup = value;
         }
     }
     #endregion
```

I would have thought providing the DescriptionField would take care of this, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is one that's obvious - I don't think the description field works the same way in the grid.  In a header field, it works to show the CD - Description when you navigate off of it.  Grid fields apparently don't work that way, even when you specify the description field in the selector the way you would in a header selector.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, let me first mention 2 major issues with the code snippet above:

1. In Acumatica **Customers** is one the specific system object types, that supports segmented keys. To create a look up for records, that support segmented keys, you should be using the `PXDimensionSelectorAttribute` instead of the `PXSelectorAttribute`. For Customer entity there are several attributes provided out of the box, like the CustomerAttribute or the CustomerActiveAttribute, that  you can use to create Customer lookups:

   [image]
2. **CustomerLookup** field must be of the `Int32?` (`int?`) type: in Acumatica users can change Customer ID with time (via the **Change ID** button on the **Customers** screen). To establish a foreign key for the Customer DAC, the better approach is to declare an integer field and associate your custom record with Customers though the Customer.BAccount field

Below is the recommended declaration of a DAC field, that creates Customer lookup in UI:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class DetailsResult : IBqlTable
{
    ...

    #region CustomerId
    public abstract class customerId : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [Customer(DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName))]
    public virtual Int32? CustomerID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    ...
}
```

With the DescriptionField property specified, **PXDimensionSelector placed on a form** will by default format selected record according to the "{SearchKey/SubstituteKey} - {DescriptionField}" pattern:

[image]

**To show DescriptionField in a grid cell**, you have to define additional column for the `CustomerID_description` field (where `_description` part is a special key word for Acumatica used specifically in this type of requests):

[image]

Comment: Using your example for CustomerID field in the DAC, [Customer] and [CustomerActive] both create errors on my aspx page when refreshing in design mode - as if they aren't valid selectors in some way.   I've tried creating the standard ID type selector with the 'substitutekey' parameter, and that works fine - except that the Description field STILL does not show up the way I would like.  Not sure how to proceed at this point.

Comment: I guess the only other option I have to propose at this moment is to file support case, so we can review your project and identify the root cause.